# OOP set a passed-in variable with new data from inside closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

When using OOP can you pass in options that link to a var outside object/closure, but that can be set inside the object/closure?

```
var Object = function (element, options) {

    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options = {
        // option1
        place: {},         
    };
    // option2
    this.place;
    this.init();

};

Object.prototype = {
   set: function(newPlace){

       // option1
       this.options.place = newPlace;
       //option 2
       this.place = newPlace;

   }
}

$.fn.object = function (option) {
    if(option instanceof Object) {
        this._object = new Object(this, option);
        return this;
    }else if(option instanceof String){
       switch (option) {
           // option2
           case 'place': return this._object.place;
               break;
           default: return this;
        }
    }
};
$.fn.object.Constructor = Object;
```

-------- THE GOAL -----------

```
var newPlace = null;
var newObject = new Object({ place : newPlace }); // or $('#').object({ place: newPlace });

newObject.set('test');

newPlace === 'test';  // <-- object should be able to set the value of external var.
```

I have tried to do this two ways but both don't return the new data set inside the closure/object.

I have labeled them option1 and option2 above.

Basically as you would expect the var is just overridden, I've also tried playing with call/apply.

Comment: `Object` is a reserved word

Comment: yer ofc, was just being generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out i may have been trying to do something that's not the right way to do it.

Best way and solution is to pass in a Function callback in options to update the local var.

```
ExampleObject = function(options){
    options = {
       update: function(){}
    }

}

ExampleObject.prototype = { 
    set: function(newPlace){
        this.options.update(newPlace);
    }
}

newObject = ExampleObject({ update: function(r){ newPlace = r; } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine:

```
var obj = function (element, options) {

    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options = {
        // option1
        place: {},         
    };
    // option2
    this.place;
    //this.init();

};

obj.prototype = {
   set: function(newPlace){

       // option1
       this.options.place = newPlace;
       //option 2
       this.place = newPlace;

   }
}

var o = new obj();
console.log(o.options.place);
o.set('foo');
console.log(o.options.place);
```

Or if you don't need multiple instances:

```
var o = {
    options: {
        place: {}
    },
    setPlace: function(place){
        this.options.place = place;
    }
};

console.log(o.options.place);
o.setPlace('foo');
console.log(o.options.place);
```

---

```
function obj(o){
    this.o = o;
}

obj.prototype.set = function(newValue){
    this.o = newValue;
};

var o = new obj({t : 't'});
console.log(o.o);
o.set({ t2: 't2' });
console.log(o.o);
```

Comment: May have not made myself clear, i need to parse in the var to be set by the object, not setting the var on the object, that's easy :) 
I want to have :
var t = {};
var o = new O({t:t});

o.set('t',newValue);
t should then equal newValue

Comment: "parse in the var"? You're not parsing anything. Please elaborate what you need

Comment: sorry pass in (not parse). I have a var used else where and wanted to pass that into the object and have it alter it's value.

Comment: @Dazzer13 A bit unclear if you want to update a property of the object or replace it completly. IS my update what you're asking for?

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i've edited my question to hopefully make it a little clearer what i want. I have put a "goal" section hopefully outlining what i want to achieve.